# How to start a MediaBrowserServiceCompat in Automotive OS?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-automotive, mediabrowserservicecompat

I am sending a notification from a worker that has an action which should open the media app. In other words, I want to start the MediaBrowserServiceCompat when the action is clicked. I tried this code:

```
    val serviceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MusicService::class.java).apply {
        action = MediaBrowserService.SERVICE_INTERFACE
    }
    val servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(applicationContext, 0, serviceIntent, 0)

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
        applicationContext,
        CHANNEL_ID
    )
        .addAction(NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.icon, "Listen", servicePendingIntent))
```

Now, it is true that the service is created and started, however, the Automotive app is not open. I compared the created service from when the launcher is clicked with the one created from my side and I found that there are a bunch of connection records in the former that make the difference:

- ConnectionRecord{f88b7c5 u10 CR automotive.app/.service.MusicService:@176fe3c}
  binding=AppBindRecord{15f60a3 automotive.app/.service.MusicService:com.manufacturer-company.launcher}
- ConnectionRecord{8946e6c u10 CR automotive.app/.service.MusicService:@4705b1f}
  binding=AppBindRecord{61fffa0 automotive.app/.service.MusicService:com.android.car.media}
- ConnectionRecord{1dee409 u0 CR automotive.app/.service.MusicService:@d3ce110}
  binding=AppBindRecord{f061b07 automotive.app/.service.MusicService:com.android.systemui}
- ConnectionRecord{d27082f u10 CR automotive.app/.service.MusicService:@d58060e}
  binding=AppBindRecord{142c759 automotive.app/.service.MusicService:com.alliance.car.mediasource}

Is there something I can do to mimic the creation of the service as It is done when the launcher is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I believe you should be able to do this using the `CAR_INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_TEMPLATE` and `CAR_EXTRA_MEDIA_COMPONENT` as described [here](https://source.android.com/docs/devices/automotive/hmi/media/technical_details#media_app_launch).

Comment: Q1: Do I need to include the android.car in my project in order to achieve this, or just using the constants values is ok?
Q2: Do you imply that my project needs to have 30 as a min SDK(CAR_EXTRA_MEDIA_COMPONENT)? Does this mean it is impossible to accomplish this feature in APIs 29 and 28?

Comment: > Do I need to include the android.car in my project in order to achieve this, or just using the constants values is ok?

Using the raw string value is OK.

> Do you imply that my project needs to have 30 as a min SDK(CAR_EXTRA_MEDIA_COMPONENT)? Does this mean it is impossible to accomplish this feature in APIs 29 and 28?

For API level 28, I believe you may need to set [CAR_EXTRA_MEDIA_PACKAGE](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/services/Car/car-lib/src/android/car/Car.java;l=1132?q=CAR_EXTRA_MEDIA_PACKAGE) instead.

Comment: Solution:
`val notificationIntent = Intent(android.car.Car.CAR_INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_TEMPLATE)
        notificationIntent.putExtra("android.car.intent.extra.MEDIA_COMPONENT", ComponentName(applicationContext, MusicService::class.java).flattenToString())`